# How do I make an existing custom entity fieldable?

Tags: entities, 9

I have a custom entity that isn't showing the ability to add fields. I need to add a field to it, and I want to do it through the UI. The entity was created in a custom module, which I can modify.

How can I make the entity fieldable?

This is the entity annotation.

```php
/**
 * Defines the Quiz entity.
 *
 * @ingroup qwizard
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "qwiz",
 *   label = @Translation("Quiz"),
 *   bundle_label = @Translation("Quiz type"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\qwizard\QwizStorage",
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\qwizard\QwizListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\qwizard\Entity\QwizViewsData",
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\qwizard\Form\QwizForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\qwizard\Form\QwizForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\qwizard\Form\QwizForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\qwizard\Form\QwizDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\qwizard\QwizAccessControlHandler",
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\qwizard\QwizHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "qwiz",
 *   revision_table = "qwiz_revision",
 *   revision_data_table = "qwiz_field_revision",
 *   admin_permission = "administer quiz entities",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "revision" = "vid",
 *     "bundle" = "type",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "uid" = "user_id",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *     "status" = "status",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}",
 *     "add-page" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/add",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/add/{qwiz_type}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/delete",
 *     "version-history" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/revisions",
 *     "revision" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/revisions/{qwiz_revision}/view",
 *     "revision_revert" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/revisions/{qwiz_revision}/revert",
 *     "revision_delete" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz/{qwiz}/revisions/{qwiz_revision}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/structure/qwizard/qwiz",
 *   },
 *   bundle_entity_type = "qwiz_type",
 *   field_ui_base_route = "entity.qwiz_type.edit_form"
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! When a question is closed, it can be edited to make it on-topic. Re-posting the same question just gets it close as duplicate.

Comment: Furthermore, the question is still not making clear what problem you are having in making the entity fieldable, or what you don't exactly understand. Does Drupal show any error message? Does the bundle edit form appear as it should, or is it a blank page? Does the entity effectively use bundles? Does Drupal simply ignore the changes you did to the annotation?